# How do I bring a variable into scope, and how to match types

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Everytime I try to load the modul which contains func1 I encounter an error, and I don't know how to fix it.

func2 and func3 work independently, and do exactly what they're supposed to do.

```
func1 xs = [x| let x = func2 (-c) xs, (_,c) <- func3 xs]
```

func1 expects a String and is supposed to deliver another String. xs is the input String, x is the output String. func 2 expects an Int and String, c is the Int, and produces another String. func3 expects a String, and puts out a Tuple. (_,c) is the Output, the first element is _ because it's irrelevant in this function, and the second element is an integer.

There is no output,  and I get the following error message:

```
Programm.hs:205:18: error:
    Variable not in scope: c :: Integer
    |
205 |         func2 (-c) xs
    |                  ^

Programm.hs:208:16: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
      Expected type: Char
        Actual type: String
    * In the expression: x
      In the expression:
        [x | let x = func2 (- c) xs, (_, c) <- func3 xs]
      In an equation for `decypher':
          func1 xs = [x | let x = func2 (- c) xs, (_, c) <- func3 xs]
    |
208 | func1 xs = [x| let x = func2 (-c) xs, (_,c) <- func3 xs]
    |                

Programm.hs:208:36: error:
    Variable not in scope: c :: Int
    |
208 | func1 xs = [x| let x = func2 (-c) xs, (_,c) <- func3 xs]
    |                                    
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Now, my questions are: Why does it say c isn't an Integer when I have defined it (I also tried it with "let (_,c) = func3 xs") as second element of the output of func3, which is necessarily an Integer?

Why does it expect x to be a Char when the output of func2 is necessarily a String?

Thank you in advance, and please have patience with me, I'm just learning Haskell :*

Comment: You reverse the order of the `let` statement and the genrator.

Comment: ```func1 xs = [x| (_,c) <- func3 xs, let x = func2 (-c) xs ]``` Is how it looks now, is that what you meant? The last error is gone, the other 2 still persist tho. Also, why did that fix that error?

Comment: No, `func1 xs = [ x | (_,c) <- func3 xs, let x = func2 (-c) xs ]`.

Comment: Yes sorry, I accidentally posted the comment before I was done writing.

Comment: these look like type errors. You will need to take a look to the types of the results of `func2`, `func3`, etc. and see what types these use as parameter.

Comment: func2 needs an integer and String as input and returns a String, func 3 expects a String as input and returns a Tuple. They do what they're supposed to do independently, and I can simulate the function of func1 by inserting c, or (-c) in this case, into func2 which I get by running func3. Your solution returns a new error, saying func2 doesn't match the expected type String. What would be the best way to post those error messages, as it's kinda unwieldy to post them in a comment.

Comment: since you did not even share the signature of these functions, it is impossible to help you with that. I suggest you ask a new question where you add some extra information about these functions.

Comment: By signatures you mean their type? Those are ```func1 :: String -> String```, ```func2 :: Int -> String -> String``` and ```func3 :: String -> (Float,Int)```. What other information should I include in a new question?

Comment: If `func3` has as result `(Float, Int)`, then that is not a list, and thus you can not write `(_, c) <- func3 xs`

Comment: That's what I figured, but ```let (_,c) = func3 xs``` didn't work either. How'd I properly define it elsewise?

Comment: well you here do not list comprehension at all, list comprehension is used when you want to iterate over a list. Strictly speaking, you could make something like `[ x | let (_, c) = func3 xs, x <- func2 (-c) xs ]`, but that would only make it more "ugly" imho.

Comment: Alright, that removed the matching type error, but now the error 

```Programm.hs:206:18: error: Variable not in scope: c :: Integer
    |
206 |         func2 (-c) xs```

persists. I assume you switched func3 and func2 by mistake in your comment?

Comment: it looks like one of the functions does not use an `Int`, but an `Integer`...

Comment: Which one would that be? ctrl+f ing for "Integer" returns no results, and all of the signatures are as I posted.

Comment: Also, why wouldn't I use list comprehension? The result is supposed to be a String, and thus a list, right?

Comment: @Saturanai: because `func2` already returns the entire list, by using that in list comprehension, you will, worst case, only add an extra loop over that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should swap the order of the `let` clause and the generator clause to:

```
func1 xs = [ x | (_,c) <- func3 xs, let x = func2 (-c) xs ]
```

but since you here only use `x` in the "yield" part of the list comprehension, you can simply omit the `let x = …`, and work with:

```
func1 xs = [ func2 (-c) xs | (_,c) <- func3 xs ]
```

Based on the [signatures of your function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58573586/how-do-i-bring-a-variable-into-scope-and-how-to-match-types/58573603#comment103463913_58573586):

```
func1 :: String -> String
func2 :: Int -> String -> String
func3 :: String -> (Float,Int)
```

your `func3` does not return a list: it returns a 2-tuple. In that case, your `func1` should probably look like:

```
func1 :: String -> String
func1 = negate . snd . func3 >>= func2
```

or simpler:

```
func1 :: String -> String
func1 xs = func2 (- (snd (func3 xs))) xs
```

Comment: ```func1 :: String -> String
func1 xs = func2 (-(snd (func3 xs))) xs```

Worked, thank you. But, if you don't mind explaining, I don't understand why it expected x to be a char in the first place, or why c wasn't in the scope, do I always have to define a variable before using it, I thought Haskell works "backwards", as it basically builds up a backlog of all expected inputs, and then works from there, as I understood it.

Comment: @Saturanal: because the signature of your function is `String -> String`, it reasons that your list comprehension will yield a list of `Char`s, and therefore tath `x` should be a `Char`.

Comment: Oh, of course. God I'm dumb. But why didn't it recognize c as defined?

Comment: Because your list comprehension is something like `let x = func2 (-c) xs in (_, c) <- func3 xs >>= return x`, and thus you use `c` in the head of the `let` statment, but it only appears in the *body*.